# How to deal with factors in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm attempting to learn how to use Rcpp in R. Can someone please point
out what the problem/s are with this code. There's probably more than one
issue.

When the `c` object is entered into `fun()` at the bottom of the code I want it to output a vector/array with the values "Home", "Elsewhere" or "Number".

I'm finding the data type slightly confusing here. My original data set is a factor. If I put this into `storage.mode()` it returns `integer`. I assume then that I have to assign the `x` argument as `IntegerVector`. This confuses me because the data contains letters, i.e "H" and "E", so how can the data be integer?
When I'm saying == "H" in the if statement i don't know if it understands what I'm saying.

```
library(Rcpp)

c <- factor(c("E", "H", "E", "12", "10", "60", "80", "11", "H", "H"))
class(c)
storage.mode(c)

cppFunction(' IntegerVector fun(IntegerVector x){

            // creates an empty character vector the size/length of x.
            CharacterVector y = x.size() ;


            int n = x.size() - 1 ;


            //loop
            for(int i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1){

            if(x[i] == "H"){
            y[i] = "Home" ;

            }else if(x[i] == "E"){
            y[i] = "Elsewhere" ;
            }else{
            y[i] = "Number" ;
            } ;


            }



            return y ;

            }')


fun(c)
```

Comment: Besides the answer provided below: Please invest some time into your coding environment. Your question from yesterday and from today contained some simple errors (missing `;`, wrong return type) that I am sure your compiler told you about. However, you seem to be missing these messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: Throughout, I will refer to `f`, not `c`. It is bad practice to name variables the same name as a builtin function or constant, such as `c`, `T`, or `F`. Therefore I change the beginning of your code as follows:

```r
library(Rcpp)

f <- factor(c("E", "H", "E", "12", "10", "60", "80", "11", "H", "H"))
```

In addition to looking at `class(f)` and `storage.mode(f)`, it's useful to look at `str(f)`:

```r
str(f)
# Factor w/ 7 levels "10","11","12",..: 6 7 6 3 1 4 5 2 7 7
```

In truth, a factor is an integer vector with "levels": a character vector corresponding to each unique integer value. Luckily, you can get this from C++ using the `.attr()` member function of `Rcpp::IntegerVector`:

```r
cppFunction('CharacterVector fun(IntegerVector x){

            // creates an empty character vector the size/length of x.
            CharacterVector y = x.size() ;

            // Get the levels of x
            CharacterVector levs = x.attr("levels");

            int n = x.size() - 1 ;


            //loop
            for(int i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 1){

            if(levs[x[i]-1] == "H"){
            y[i] = "Home" ;

            }else if(levs[x[i]-1] == "E"){
            y[i] = "Elsewhere" ;
            }else{
            y[i] = "Number" ;
            } ;


            }



            return y ;

            }')

fun(f)
# [1] "Elsewhere" "Home"      "Elsewhere" "Number"    "Number"    "Number"   
# [7] "Number"    "Number"    "Home"      "Home"
```

So, to get what you want, you had to do three things:

1. Change the return type from `IntegerVector` to `CharacterVector` (though you were completely right that the input should be `IntegerVector`)
2. Get the levels of the factor using `CharacterVector levs = x.attr("levels");`
3. Compare `levs[x[i]-1]` to `"H"`, etc., rather than `x[i]` -- `x[i]` will always be an integer, giving the element of the vector of levels it corresponds to. We do `-1` since C++ is 0-indexed and R is 1-indexed.

Other notes:

It is clear, as you say, that "[you're] attempting to learn how to use Rcpp() in R." You'll definitely want to spend some time with resources such as [Rcpp for Everyone](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/250_factor.html) (that's the chapter on factors), the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-factor-generation/) (this specific link is an article on factors), [Hadley's chapter on Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html), and definitely the Rcpp vignettes available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).